# How to change rows per page items for a specific page in Vuetify's v-data-table?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, v-data-table

At the moment I am using Vuetify's v-data-table pagination, which works fine.
However for this particular use case I need to change the rows per page for a specific page to unlimited.

A solution I thought of, but requires a lot more work regarding filtering, is to use server-side filtering to fetch 10 and disable the pagination limit within the data-table.

Does aynone have an easier solution/fix to my problem?

Answer (score 0):

1. Add the props `:options.sync="options"` in your `<v-data-table>`

Like this :

```
<v-data-table
    :headers="headers"
    :items="desserts"
    :options.sync="options"
    :server-items-length="totalDesserts"
    :loading="loading"
    class="elevation-1"
></v-data-table>
```

2. Then add the object options in the data of your vue.

   ```
    options: {
      itemsPerPage: -1,
    },
   ```

Like this :

```
    new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      vuetify: new Vuetify(),
      data () {
        return {
          options: {
            itemsPerPage: -1,
          },
          ...
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The problem with the provided solution is that the itemsPerPage would be applicable to all pages, and not one.